# Java Adjacency list implementation of graph with directed weighted edges

Tags: java, graph, linked-list, adjacency-list

I am trying to implement a directed weighted edge graph in Java using adjacency lists. It consists of an array with the size equal to the number of vertices, each entry of the array is a `LinkedList` of the successors of that each particular `Vertex`.

I want to add weight to each edge, I was thinking of doing this by adding a weight label to each `successor` Object in the `LinkedList`, furthermore I want to add other variables per `Vertex` for future use. If I want to do this, I would have to create a new Data structure for the vertices and a separate one as an adjacency lists. What would be an efficient design to combine both as a single Data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should represent your graph as a HashMap where key is label of vertices and value is vertex objects.

```
HashMap<String,Vertex> graph = new HashMap<String,Vertex>();
```

Vertex is a class encapsulating vertex attributes.There will be an attribute HashMap for adjacent vertices with weights.

```
HashMap<Vertex,Integer> adjListWithWeights = new HashMap<Vertex,Integer>();
```

You can add more functionality and attributes to your graph through Vertex class.